# How to use a loop to create radiobuttons in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to create multiple radio buttons. Each has its own name and location on grid. There are also several variables involved.

I stored all the data to create these radio buttons in a tuple
(I know that FONTS does not cause a problem, its stored above this but isn't shown here):

```
    self.unitType = IntVar()
    self.matPropSel = IntVar()
    self.secProfSel = IntVar()
    self.endSupSel = IntVar()
    self.loadTypeSel = IntVar()

     self.RADIOLABELS = (  # Text, Font, Variable, Value, Row, Column
        ('English', self.FONTS[3], self.unitType, 1, 3, 1),
        ('metric', self.FONTS[3], self.unitType, 2, 4, 1),
        ('select preset', self.FONTS[3], self.matPropSel, 1, 6, 1),
        ('manual entry', self.FONTS[3], self.matPropSel, 2, 7, 1),
        ('select preset', self.FONTS[3], self.secProfSel, 1, 10, 1),
        ('manual entry', self.FONTS[3], self.secProfSel, 2, 11, 1),
        ('one end', self.FONTS[3], self.endSupSel, 1, 15, 1),
        ('both ends', self.FONTS[3], self.endSupSel, 2, 16, 1),
        ('point', self.FONTS[3], self.loadTypeSel, 1, 18, 1),
        ('uniform distribution', self.FONTS[3], self.loadTypeSel, 2, 19, 1),
        ('uniform variation', self.FONTS[3], self.loadTypeSel, 3, 20, 1)
     )
```

So, how would I use a for loop to go through this tuple and generate a radio button from each line? Do all of the variables have to be the same? I am having problems with them.

Here is my attempt at a loop:

```
    outerIndexer = 0
    for labels in self.RADIOLABELS:
        Radiobutton(self, text=self.RADIOLABELS[outerIndexer][0], font=self.RADIOLABELS[outerIndexer][1],
                    variable=self.RADIOLABELS[outerIndexer][2], value=self.RADIOLABELS[outerIndexer][3])\
            .grid(row=self.RADIOLABELS[outerIndexer][4], column=self.RADIOLABELS[outerIndexer][5])
    outerIndexer += 1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly is it that you do not understand? Or add your own attempt at the for loop so that someone can help you out and correct some likely doubt that you might have.

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil certainly

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this by looping through the RADIOLABELS. Note: it is also recommended to save the button to a list so it doesn't get lost.

```
self.RADIOLABELS = (  # Text, Font, Variable, Value, Row, Column
    ('English', self.FONTS[3], self.unitType, 1, 3, 1),
    ('metric', self.FONTS[3], self.unitType, 2, 4, 1),
    ('select preset', self.FONTS[3], self.matPropSel, 1, 6, 1),
    ('manual entry', self.FONTS[3], self.matPropSel, 2, 7, 1),
    ('select preset', self.FONTS[3], self.secProfSel, 1, 10, 1),
    ('manual entry', self.FONTS[3], self.secProfSel, 2, 11, 1),
    ('one end', self.FONTS[3], self.endSupSel, 1, 15, 1),
    ('both ends', self.FONTS[3], self.endSupSel, 2, 16, 1),
    ('point', self.FONTS[3], self.loadTypeSel, 1, 18, 1),
    ('uniform distribution', self.FONTS[3], self.loadTypeSel, 2, 19, 1),
    ('uniform variation', self.FONTS[3], self.loadTypeSel, 3, 20, 1)
 )

radiobuttons = []
for _Text, _Font, _Variable, _Value, _Row, _Column in self.RADIOLABELS: # it will unpack the values during each iteration
    _Radio = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = _Text, font = _Font, variable = _Variable, value = _Value)
                           # ^ root should be the frame/Tk you're trying to place it on, it will be self if this is a direct subclass of a Frame or Tk
            # ^ or Radiobutton(.....) if you did from tkinter import *
    _Radio.grid(row = _Row, column = _Column)
    radiobuttons.append(_Radio)
```

Comment: This definitely gets me closer to where I need to be. Although, I am still getting an                                                                                                                            self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'    Should I be declaring those variables differently? I think the problem has to do with them because I made a bunch of labels the same way and they were fine. @abccd

Comment: replace `root` with whatever your master/frame/Tk is called. You never specified it, so I just went with the default `root`. If you did `from tkinter import *`, I would recommend you lowercase the variable names, so it doesn't get messed up.

Comment: yes, I had already changed this to 'self', should it be Tk instead if I am using that to inherit from? @abccd

Comment: How did you import tkinter? If self is in a subclass of a frame/Tk then yes, if not, use the one you usually use. It shouldn't be caused by my code.

Comment: from tkinter import * and my class inherits from it as Classname(Tk) and in the initializer it uses Tk.__init__(self)

Comment: Use `Radiobutton(....)` instead of `tk.Radiobutton(....)` then try. And you will probably want to use the new version from my answer or else `Text` will get override by the Text I created. If everything I suggested doesn't work, maybe post your whole code to assist the debug process

Comment: I am getting errors before the loop is even called. My program fails as soon as it tries to define the tuple that has all of the information in it. Do you think it has to with the variables? Can I not store master variables in a list? @abccd

Comment: @thisissparzo He would probably need the error traceback in order to help you.

Comment: I found the problem by changing:                                                
    self.unitType = IntVar()...                                                                                           to:                                                                                             
     self.unitType = None.....                                                                                                                                            The problem I have now is that all of the radio buttons are not independent. Thank you guys in the meantime. Ill put up a sep q.

Comment: @abccd, could you please elaborate on why it is recommended to save the radiobuttons on a list, even considering a hypothetical application which does not reference the radiobuttons? Is it due to maintenance purposes?